# How many ways can we select 3 elements from the multiset G = {A, B, B, C, C, C}?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The problem is to determine how many distinct sets of 3 elements taken from multiset G.

So we have the following 6 ways:

(A, B, C)
(A, B, B)
(A, C, C)
(B, C, C)
(B, B, C)
(C, C, C)

*Note that element (A) when chosen, will only appear 1 time in the selection sub-set, because it only has 1 element (A).

But what is the formula to find this amount?

The problem is actually finding a generic formula for any case, as shown in the figure below:
[image]

Where:

a = number of elementos **A**,

b = number of elementos **B**,

c = number of elementos **C**,   and so on...

What is the formula or method to find how many different ways we can form a set of **(p)** elements, selecting **(p)** elements from a multiset **G**, with **(t)** types of elements with certain repetitions?

Comment: Please do not refer to **sets** as **groups**. That has a totally different meaning in math.

Comment: Thank you almagest. I corrected this in the statement. thanks!

Comment: $G$ is actually a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), not a set.

Comment: Really, even better, is a multiset! Thank you Rob!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

coefficient of $x^p$ in $(1+x^1+x^2+x^3........x^a)(1+x^1+x^2.......x^b)(1+x^1+x^2........x^c).....................$ is your required answer.

As your question just depends on how many A or B or C we took. For example if you  take 3 A then use $x^3$ from first set, take 2 B then use $x^2$ from second set and so on.

This of course is not easy to calculate generally, but if it is given that a,b,c,d.......x (all of them)$\ge$p, then it is a very general result giving value ${t+p-1 \choose p}.$

Comment: Thank you very much Aryan! brilliant method of solving the problem generically. Your solution is fast and powerful! allows us to see all classes of solutions for a group by choosing any (p). Congratulations and thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use inclusion/exclusion:

You are looking for $$x_A+x_B+x_C = 3, 0\le x_A \le 1, 0\le x_B \le 2, 0\le x_C \le 3$$

The total number of solutions with no upper bounds is $$\dbinom{3+3-1}{3-1}$$

Suppose the upper bound for $x_A$ was violated. This implies $x_A \ge 2$. So, subtract 2 from the RHS: $$x_A^\prime+x_B+x_C = 3-2 = 1$$ So, the upper bound is violated in $$\dbinom{1+3-1}{3-1}$$ ways.

Next, suppose the upper bound for $x_B$ was violated. This implies $x_B \ge 3$. So, subtract 3 from the RHS: $$x_A+x_B^\prime+x_C = 3-3 = 0$$ So, the upper bound is violated in $$\dbinom{0+3-1}{3-1}$$ ways.

There are no ways to violate more than one upper bound at the same time, so the total is $$\dbinom{5}{2}-\dbinom{3}{2}-\dbinom{2}{2} = 10-3-1=6$$

---

For a general formula: instead of using $a,b,c,\ldots, x$, I will use $x_1,x_2,x_3, \ldots, x_t$ so that the indexes are able to be iterated. Let $[t] = \{1,2,\ldots, t\}$.

$$\sum_{A \subseteq [t]}(-1)^{|A|}\dbinom{p+t-1-|A|-\displaystyle \sum_{a \in A}x_a}{t-1}$$

Note: for this formula, we are defining $\dbinom{n}{r}$ to take the value of $0$ for all $n<r$.

Comment: Thank you very much InterstellarProbe! Brilliant demonstration! Excuse me, i just didn't understand what the sum: $$ p + t - 1 - |A| - \sum_{aEA} x_a $$,  because this is always resulting in a negative value! The binomial would always be zero?

Comment: Example: $p=3, t=3, x_i=i$ $$\begin{matrix}A=\emptyset : & p+t-1-|A|-\sum_{a \in A}x_a = 3+3-1-0-0=5 \\ A = \{1\}: & p+t-1-|A|-\sum_{a \in A}x_a = 3+3-1-1-1 = 3 \\ A = \{2\}: & p+t-1-|A|-\sum_{a \in A} x_a = 3+3-1-1-2 = 2 \\ \text{otherwise} & p+t-1-|A|-\sum_{a \in A}x_a < 2 = t-1\end{matrix}$$ This is the breakdown for the problem above. All other binomials will be zero.

Comment: Ah! Perfect! now I understand. "A" starts with a void (zero) up to (t-1). Can this formula be used for when $x_i$ takes on any value? and not only when $x_i$ = i? Thank you again!

Comment: Of course. Example: $p=5, t=3, x_1=3, x_2=1, x_3=2$: $$\begin{array}{c|c}A & p+t-1-|A|-\sum_{a \in A}x_a \\ \hline \emptyset & 5+3-1-0-0 = 7 \\ \{1\} & 5+3-1-1-3 = 3 \\ \{2\} & 5+3-1-1-1 = 5 \\ \{3\} & 5+3-1-1-2 = 4 \\ \{1,2\} & 5+3-1-2-4=1 \\ \{1,3\} & 5+3-1-2-5 = 0 \\ \{2,3\} & 5+3-1-2-3=2 \\ \{1,2,3\} & 5+3-1-3-6 = -2\end{array}$$ So the sum becomes: $$\binom{7}{2}-\binom{3}{2}-\binom{5}{2}-\binom{4}{2}+\binom{1}{2}+\binom{0}{2}+\binom{2}{2}-\binom{-2}{2} = \binom{7}{2}-\binom{3}{2}-\binom{5}{2}-\binom{4}{2}+0+0+\binom{2}{2}-0 = 3$$

Comment: To demonstrate, the possible outcomes with $p=5,t=3,x_1=3,x_2=1,x_3=2$ are $11123$, $11133$, $11233$. Those are the only possible outcomes.

Comment: Of course, as $t$ increases, this formula becomes increasingly difficult to calculate. There are $2^t$ possible subsets of $[t]$, so this formula grows exponentially.

Comment: Thanks again Interstellar! Excuse me for my stupid account error. Its formula is spectacular and powerful! You helped me a lot. Thanks, thanks!!!